# Need pcre for pattern like "xxyy.zz"

Tags: python, perl, pcre

I need pcre for pattern like "xxyy.zz", where x,y and z can be any alphabet.

Language: Python

What I have tried:
For 's = "xx"', 're.match(r"([a-z])\1{1}",s)' works but for my full string it does not work. For example for 's = "xxyy"', 're.match(r"([a-z])\1{1}([a-z])\1{1}",s)' does not work...

Please guide me how to fix this pcre.

Comment: In what language are you writing your PCRE expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each alpha group needs to be in parens and followed by a `\1` style group reference.  I don't think you can use a `{2}` quantifier here, so the pairs needs need to be written serially:

```
>>> re.search(r'([a-z])\1([a-z])\2\.([a-z])\3', 'abccdd.eef').group(0)
'ccdd.ee'
```